# Flutter Blue Scan Results Empty

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

When running the following sample code from Flutter Blue's pub page to scan for nearby devices, the list returns as empty on my Android device. When going to settings I see the name of my BLE device.

The code is:

```
FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;

flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
    // this code is run almost immediately rather than after a 4 second timeout.
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
        print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
    }
});

//Ive tried with and without the following line
flutterBlue.stopScan();
```

Bluetooth and location permissions are enabled on the app.

What are some things that could be causing this?

Comment: call `flutterBlue.stopScan()` only when you want to stop the scan, and i suggest to increase the timeout duration, like `Duration(seconds: 60)`, and be sure to give the permission of the phone location to your app if your device with new Android version

Comment: @GNassro Ive tried it without stop scan as well, and with larger time outs. Regardless of the timeout size it hits the callback at the same time. Is there a specific place in a flutter app you need to do this? I have it in initState for the time being.

Comment: Did you try `await flutterBlue.startScan()` and `stopScan()`? @Bigbob556677